# Android user-permissions in Manifest

Tags: android, android-manifest, user-permissions, android-internet

I declared `<user-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` in my `AndroidManifest` since I thought it was the goto way of getting user-permissions. 
But I got this warning : `"Element user-permission not allowed here"`

Via a quick google search I could not figure out what the problem or what the best practice is here.

I am using SDK 21 and up.

Comment: Can you post your manifest please?

Comment: It's `<uses-permission>`

Comment: Change what @Irshu have Said.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Change this.**

```
<user-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> //Not Valid
```

**To this.**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> //Correct One
```